# Can I improve my question about the availability of specific hardware to make it on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have posted a question about the [availability of Windows 10 barcode handheld devices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38125382/87698), and it was closed with the following reason (emphasis mine):

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, **describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it**.

I have re-read my question and I am pretty sure that I have done exactly that:

- *Describe the problem*: I need a device with a barcode scanner to sell/recommend with my Windows 10 app.
- *What has been done so far to solve it*: I've shared my research on existing devices and alternatives.

In addition, I believe that the question is clear enough not to "*attract opinionated answers*", and the availability of such devices is rare enough not to "*attract spam*".

Can I rephrase my question to make it on-topic, or is the problem itself fundamentally off-topic here?

Comment: I don't think so. List questions are not welcome here, for better or worse. There is no way *not* to make this a list question.

Comment: Nope. At best, your question is, "Does this hardware exist?" There's no way to make that on-topic.

Comment: I think it's fundamentally off-topic. You might try [Hardware recs](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) help centre to see whether you could write it in such a way that it would be on-topic there. In its present form I think it would be off-topic there too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. At best, your question is, "Does this hardware exist?" There's no way to make that on-topic.